# Using prototype on basic data

Tags: javascript, prototype

there are two ways to define a constructor with basic data:

```
var Person1 = function() {
    this.name = "Wayne";
};
var Person2 = function() {};
Person2.prototype.name = "Wayne";
```

whats the difference between that?

Comment: Ah, I thought that you were referring to the BatMan and then I checked your name... :D

Comment: All instances of `Person2` will share the same `name`, whereas each `Person1` will have an own `name`.

Answer (score 2):

> Whats the difference between that?

With a string or other primitive, there isn't a *huge* difference, but with the first one *each* instance gets its own `name` property with the value `"Wayne"`; with the second, there's only *one* `name` property, on the prototype, and it has the value `"Wayne"`.

ASCII-art can help here, suppose we have:

```
var p1 = new Person();
var p2 = new Person();
var p3 = new Person();
```

With your first code, we get this:

```
+-----------------+      +-----------------+      +-----------------+
|       p1        |      |       p2        |      |       p3        |
+-----------------+      +-----------------+      +-----------------+
| __proto__       |---+  | __proto__       |---+  | __proto__       |---+
| name: "Wayne"   |   |  | name: "Wayne"   |   |  | name: "Wayne"   |   |
+-----------------+   |  +-----------------+   |  +-----------------+   |
                      |                        |                        |
                      |  +---------------------+                        |
                      |  |                                              |
                      |  +----------------------------------------------+
                      |  |  +------------------+
                      +--+->| Person.prototype |
                            +------------------+
                            |                  |
                            +------------------+
```

With your second code, using the prototype, we get this:

```
+-----------------+      +-----------------+      +-----------------+
|       p1        |      |       p2        |      |       p3        |
+-----------------+      +-----------------+      +-----------------+
| __proto__       |---+  | __proto__       |---+  | __proto__       |---+
+-----------------+   |  +-----------------+   |  +-----------------+   |
                      |                        |                        |
                      |  +---------------------+                        |
                      |  |                                              |
                      |  +----------------------------------------------+
                      |  |  +------------------+
                      +--+->| Person.prototype |
                            +------------------+
                            |  name: "Wayne"   |
                            +------------------+
```

It's important to note, though, that when you do this:

```
p1.name = "Greyson";
```

...that does *not* change `Person.prototype.name` (in the normal case); it gives `p1` its *own* `name` property, giving us this:

```
+-----------------+      +-----------------+      +-----------------+
|       p1        |      |       p2        |      |       p3        |
+-----------------+      +-----------------+      +-----------------+
| __proto__       |---+  | __proto__       |---+  | __proto__       |---+
| name: "Greyson" |   |  +-----------------+   |  +-----------------+   |
+-----------------+   |                        |                        |
                      |                        |                        |
                      |  +---------------------+                        |
                      |  |                                              |
                      |  +----------------------------------------------+
                      |  |  +------------------+
                      +--+->| Person.prototype |
                            +------------------+
                            |  name: "Wayne"   |
                            +------------------+
```

It's an assymetric process: When you *write* to a property, in the normal case, it creates or updates one on the actual object you're using; but when you *read* from a property, it looks first at that object to see if it has it, and if it doesn't it goes to the object's prototype object, then to *that* object's prototype object, etc. as necessary. So when you try to use `name`'s value later:

```
console.log(p1.name);
console.log(p2.name);
console.log(p3.name);
```

...the JavaScript engine looks first at the instance (the `p1`, `p2`, or `p3`) to see if it has the property and uses that property's value if it does; if the instance doesn't, the engine looks at the prototype, and uses the property there if it has it.

---

I say "in the normal case" above because properties can have getters and setters, which can change how this works. I won't go into it here, just flagging it up.